# Why does pdfLaTeX fail when I try to use `begin{lstlisting}` inside a user-defined environment?

Tags: listings, errors, environments

I'm having trouble with the `listings` package. I can't compile the following minimal example through `pdfLaTeX`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, twoside, openright, english]{memoir}

\usepackage{listings}

\newenvironment{haskellCode}
{%
  \begin{lstlisting}%
}
{%
  \end{lstlisting}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{haskellCode}
  test
\end{haskellCode}
\end{document}
```

The compilation process just stops and appears to ask me for input:

```
* <The hell? I'll just try pressing ENTER then...>
(Please type a command or say `\end')
*
```

But if I move the code in `haskellCode` directly into the document (i.e. use `lstlisting` directly) it compiles fine.

Any idea what's happening and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `lstlisting` environment is in many respects similar to the `verbatim` environment and TeX has to "see" explicitly the `\end{lstlisting}` to know it's finished.

The solution is to use `\lstnewenvironment`:

```
\lstnewenvironment{haskellCode}{}{}
```

is what you need; of course you can add many customizations to the "start" and "end" parts.