# lstlisting in a newenvironment

Tags: macros, listings, environments, verbatim

I have a problem with the `lstlisting` package. I want to define an `\newenvironment` with one obligatory parameter, which will be the caption name for the `lstlisting`. I will also have other `lstlisting` environments, that is why I am trying to define them separately.

I am also having some difficulties with `\lstinline` command (I set up a `\newcommand` to gain easier coding), which typesets keywords in normal text. Why can't it be in captions and similar?

I suppose something could be wrong with the preamble, that's why all the packages used are listed.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=3cm, bottom=3cm, heightrounded, outer=3cm, inner=3cm, marginparwidth=1.5cm, marginparsep=0.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{multicol} 
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx} 
\usepackage{epstopdf} 
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{fancyvrb} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{paralist} 
\usepackage{listings} 
\usepackage{pifont} 
\usepackage{indentfirst} 

\lstset{language=[Visual]Basic, %
keywordstyle=\color{blue},commentstyle=\color{ForestGreen},stringstyle=\color{Maroon},%
basicstyle=\ttfamily\normalsize, frame=lines, %
showspaces=false, showstringspaces=false,%
tabsize=4, aboveskip=10pt, belowskip=10pt, %
lineskip=2pt, numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny, stepnumber=1, numbersep=5pt,%
numberblanklines=false, %
breaklines, breakatwhitespace, prebreak=\_, breakindent=0pt %
}

\lstset{morekeywords={Or, Loop, Until, To, As, Single, Module, Double, ByVal}}

\lstset{emph={Console}, emphstyle=\color{Aquamarine}}

\newenvironment{case}[1]{\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Case}%
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={#1}]}%
{\end{lstlisting}}

\newcommand{\code}[1]{\lstinline[basicstyle=\rmfamily\normalsize, prebreak=, keywordstyle=\ttfamily]{#1}} 

\begin{document}

Example with inline, that works: \code{Console, Sub in Module}.

\begin{case}{Hello world} %doesn't work
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!")
        Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
End Module
\end{case}

\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you seen `\lstnewenvironment`? Have a look in the package manual or search this site!

Comment: I checked and have a question: do I have to put the optional parameter in {} or [] when calling the new environment?

Comment: For the issue with your `\code` macro, this is caused by trying to place verbatim-type material in a macro or as an argument. See eg [Any ideas why this \newcommand{\n}{\lstinline|\n|} macro doesn't work?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17153/any-ideas-why-this-newcommand-n-lstinline-n-macro-doesnt-work) and 
[Wrapping code (listings, verbatim, or other method) inside a newcommand](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25597/wrapping-code-listings-verbatim-or-other-method-inside-a-newcommand)

Comment: Related: [Why does pdfLaTeX fail when I try to use `begin{lstlisting}` inside a user-defined environment?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27640/why-does-pdflatex-fail-when-i-try-to-use-beginlstlisting-inside-a-user-defin). @cmhughes: I am not sure if it has been fully resolved, but I have now posted an answer. (Note I do not have enough reputation to cast close votes anyway.)

Comment: Related: [Problem with creating a newenvironment in LaTeX](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2606794/53974)

Comment: Other issues with lstlistings: [float environment (figure)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15026/250119),
[minipage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/434253/250119),,
[minipage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/104089/250119),
[custom `\section`+`\label`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/122050/250119),
[syntax highlight F#](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78992/250119),
[complex macro, include in 2-column table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/148180/250119),
[(*this question*) caption name](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86705/250119),

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Unless you tell it otherwise, when processing an environment started with `\begin{lstlisting}`, `listings` looks for an `\end{lstlisting}` to signal the end of the environment.

Your environment `case` hides the `\end{lstlisting}` in a way that `listings` doesn't expect. If you remove the `\end{lstlisting}` from your environment definition and put it before every instance of `\end{case}`, it works. But this clearly isn't a solution, and `listings` recognises this, so it provides `\lstnewenvironment` for creating your own environments whose contents you want `listings` to process. This is documented in [section 4.16 of the `listings` package documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/listings/listings.pdf#nameddest=subsection.4.16).

You should therefore replace your definition of `case` using `\newenvironment` with eg `\lstnewenvironment{case}[1]{\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Case}\lstset{caption={#1}}}{}`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=3cm, bottom=3cm, heightrounded, outer=3cm, inner=3cm, marginparwidth=1.5cm, marginparsep=0.5cm]{geometry} 
%\usepackage{tocloft}
%\usepackage{amsmath} 
%\usepackage{eurosym}
%\usepackage{url}
%\usepackage{array}
%\usepackage{tabularx}
%\usepackage{multirow} 
%\usepackage{multicol} 
%\usepackage{graphics}
%\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx} 
%\usepackage{epstopdf} 
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} 
%\usepackage{verbatim}
%\usepackage{fancyvrb} 
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\usepackage{paralist} 
\usepackage{listings} 
%\usepackage{pifont} 
%\usepackage{indentfirst} 

\lstset{language=[Visual]Basic, %
keywordstyle=\color{blue},commentstyle=\color{ForestGreen},stringstyle=\color{Maroon},%
basicstyle=\ttfamily\normalsize, frame=lines, %
showspaces=false, showstringspaces=false,%
tabsize=4, aboveskip=10pt, belowskip=10pt, %
lineskip=2pt, numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny, stepnumber=1, numbersep=5pt,%
numberblanklines=false, %
breaklines, breakatwhitespace, prebreak=\_, breakindent=0pt %
}

\lstset{morekeywords={Or, Loop, Until, To, As, Single, Module, Double, ByVal}}

\lstset{emph={Console}, emphstyle=\color{Aquamarine}}

\lstnewenvironment{case}[1]{\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Case}%
\lstset{caption={#1}}}%
{}

\newcommand{\code}[1]{\lstinline[basicstyle=\rmfamily\normalsize, prebreak=, keywordstyle=\ttfamily]{#1}} 

\begin{document}

Example with inline, that works: \code{Console, Sub in Module}.

\begin{case}{Hello world}
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!")
        Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
End Module
\end{case}

\end{document}
```

(I have commented out any packages in the preamble that I think turn out not to be relevant.)

If you still have issues with your captions, perhaps you can ask about those in more detail.