# wrap listings package - Problem with verbatim argument

Tags: listings, verbatim, xparse

I would like to define a command that wraps a `lstlisting` environment in some other environments (esp. a minipage). I understand that working with verbatim arguments is a difficult task. I tried the `xparse` package which provides the argument type `v`, but code like

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\prog}{v}{\begin{lstlisting}#1\end{lstlisting}}
```

does not work. Can anybody give me advice on that?

Is it any easier if I use an environment instead of a command?

Comment: The `lstlisting` environment cannot go in the argument of a command. It can go in a `minipage` without any problem.

Comment: There isn't any way to circumvent this? Maybe I have to find out how lstlisting handles the "verbatim problem" and try to mimick it...

Comment: No, there isn't. Moreover, when you put some tokens in the argument to a command you lose the line endings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `lstlisting` environment with `minipage` using [`\lstnewenvironment`](ftp://ftp.gust.org.pl/TeX/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf):

```
\lstnewenvironment{wrappedlisting}{\noindent\minipage{\linewidth}}{\endminipage}
```

And use it like the any other environment:

```
\begin{wrappedlisting}
...
\end{wrappedlisting}
```