# Create new environment on top of another

Tags: environments, tcolorbox

I'm trying to create a new environment on top of `tcblisting` (from `tcolorbox` package) using `environ` package. Getting weird error about Runaway argument. The MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{environ}

\tcbuselibrary{listings}

\NewEnviron{CodeListing}[2][]{%
  \begin{tcblisting}{listing only}
    \BODY
  \end{tcblisting}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{CodeListing}
  bool someVar;
\end{CodeListing}
\end{document}
```

The error is

```
Runaway argument?
! File ended while scanning use of \next.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> mwe.tex
```

If I remove the `tcblisting` environment in the new environment, Everything is fine. What is going wrong here ?

Comment: I'm getting similar error when I try to create new command and use `tcblisting` environment inside the new command.

Comment: Verbatim material (as the one in `tcblisting`) can't be placed in a macro argument. See this related thread: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86705/27635.

Answer (score 5):

Why the combination of `tcblisting` and `environ` does not work, was explained in the comments. But it is possible to create a new environment using `\newtcblisting`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\tcbuselibrary{listings}

\newtcblisting{CodeListing}[2][]{listing only}

\begin{document}
\begin{CodeListing}{something for the mandatory argument}
  bool someVar;
\end{CodeListing}
\end{document}
```