# newenvironment for tcolorbox and lstlisting

Tags: environments

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings, tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings,skins,theorems,xparse}

\newenvironment{mybox}
  {\begin{tcolorbox}\begin{lstlisting}}
  {\end{lstlisting}\end{tcolorbox}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}\begin{lstlisting}
This is my \LaTeX\ box.
\end{lstlisting}\end{tcolorbox}

% \begin{mybox}
% This is my \LaTeX\ box too!
% \end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

My environment doesn't work. Maybe I need a primer on `\newenvironment`?

Comment: Use `\tcbuselibrary{listings}` and `\newtcblisting` instead.  This gets around the problems with the way `listings` looks for the end of the environment.

Comment: The issue is explained e.g. in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86765/82917. A solution (to a rather similar question, though not en exact duplicate) is given in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/132358/82917.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of the tcolorbox manual section 4.13 p 302:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcblisting{mybox}[2][]{%
colback=red!5!white,
colframe=red!75!black,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
title=#2,#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}[listing only]{Listing Box}
This is my \LaTeX\ box.
\end{mybox}
\bigskip

\begin{mybox}[listing side text]{Listing Box}
This is my \LaTeX\ box.
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: newtcblisting]