# Combining newenvironment, quote and lstlisting (mcode)

Tags: macros, listings, environments

I am trying to combine various packages and commands with PdfLaTeX (through MikTex on MS Windows), including `newenvironment`, `quote`, `mcode` and `lstlisting`, to create an environment to define multiple inlined text boxes that include commentary plus snippets of marked-up code. Simple experiments with `quote` and `newenvironment` work as shown in the documentation (e.g. Oetiker et al's not so short guide to latex), but addition of `mcode/lstlisting` disrupts compilation. The reported error message is that 
`\end{document}` is encountered prior to `\end{quote}`. I've tinkered with the order of the individual elements but to no avail.

The following does NOT work:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[numbered,autolinebreaks,useliterate]{mcode}

\newenvironment{testcode}[2]%
{\small\begin{quote}title: #1
\begin{lstlisting}
#2\end{lstlisting}
}{\end{quote}}

\begin{document}

\begin{testcode}{some code}
{myvar= 1;}\end{testcode}

\end{document}
```

I left the list of all packages in the original LaTeX doc because I am unsure about package dependencies.

The following substitution of the later part of the code DOES compile and typesets very much as I would like, but then I cannot pass variables to `newenvironment`, removing some of the flexibility I was looking for:

```
\newenvironment{testcode}
{\small\begin{quote}}{\end{quote}}

\begin{document}

\begin{testcode}{
   title: some code
   \begin{lstlisting}
      myvar= 1;
   \end{lstlisting}}
\end{testcode}

\end{document}
```

I also attempted substituting `newenvironment` with `lstnewenvironment`, somewhat according to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86705/lstlisting-in-a-newenvironment) solution, but did not get rid of the error. Appreciate some help with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use carefully LaTeX commands in the definition of listings environments. Here I show you how to define `testcode` with `\lstnewenvironment` and also a different way.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% this is for “secondtest”
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{
  position=top,
  margin=3pc,
  justification=raggedright,
  singlelinecheck=false,
  font=small,
}
\usepackage[numbered,autolinebreaks,useliterate]{mcode}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum} % Just for this example

\lstnewenvironment{testcode}[1]
  {\small\quote Title: #1}
  {\endquote}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily} % just to better see the listings

\lstnewenvironment{secondtest}[2][]
 {\small
  \lstset{
    aboveskip=\topsep,
    belowskip=\topsep,
    belowcaptionskip=\topsep,
    title=Title: #2,
    xleftmargin=3pc,
    #1}
 }
 {}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{testcode}{some code}
myvar= 1;
\end{testcode}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{secondtest}{some code}
myvar= 1;
\end{secondtest}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also add other `listings` options to `secondtest` in the following format:

```
\begin{secondtest}[<listings options>]{the title}
<the code>
\end{secondtest}
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up... the first answer is enough, but I'll look further into the alternative.