# Environment for two columns with lstlistings

Tags: tables, listings, environments

In order to reduce copy-pasting, I want to create an environment that will produce a two-column table with headers and two listings in different languages, like below:

```
\begin{tabular}{l l}
Python & Haskell \\
\hline \\
\lstset{language=Python}
\begin{lstlisting}
A
\end{lstlisting}
&
\lstset{language=Haskell}
\begin{lstlisting}
B
\end{lstlisting}
\end{tabular}
```

I want to use it like below, hiding everything but code:

```
\begin{comparison}
A
\vs
B
\end{comparison}
```

So far I tried making two new environments (instead of a `\vs` command inside) with `\lstnewenvironment`, where first environment had `\tabularx` command and second `\endtabularx`. I also tried creating normal `\newenvironment` for this tabular, `&` for `\vs` command and manually inserting `\begin{lstlistings}` and `\end{lstlistings}` with code, but it stopped compiling when I put `lstlistings` inside.

How can I create such an environment?

**EDIT**:
The most compact version I've came up with until now is

```
\newenvironment{comparison}
{\begin{parcolumns}[nofirstindent,distance=0pt,colwidths={1=0.35\textwidth}]{2}}
{\end{parcolumns}}

\lstnewenvironment{python}
{Python
\lstset{language=Python,frame=t}}
{}

\lstnewenvironment{haskell}
{Haskell
\lstset{language=Haskell,frame=t}}
{}
```

which is used like that:

```
\begin{comparison}
\colchunk{
\begin{python}
A
\end{python}
}
\colchunk{
\begin{haskell}
B
\end{haskell}
}
\end{comparison}
```

I'm still unable to hide `\colchunk{}` within `python` or `haskell` environments.

Comment: *How can I create such an environment?* With difficulty :)  You cannot simply use `\newenvironment` because precautions have to be taken to define a new environment that is supposed to have some verbatim content. The `listings` package provides the `\lstnewenvironment` macro to create new environments for listings, but those environments can only contain *one* listing. You may have to define a new macro based on `\lstnewenvironment` to achieve what you want.

Comment: If your document is meant to be two-sided (like a book), an easier, though perhaps not as satisfactory, alternative would be to have two associated listings at the top or bottom of consecutive even and odd pages; the reader would then be able to compare them easily.

Comment: @Jubobs: This is an article paper, so it won't work.
Also, I think it's impossible to do this environment for two listings, since there is no "command" sort of lstlisting, like `\tabularx` instead of `\begin{tabularx}`. Also, tabularx doesn't work well with verbatim-like environments inside, so I'm thinking of multicols/tabular and adding lstlistings environments manually (with options and headers hidden in my command).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is impossible with `lstlisting` environments, because their contents is verbatim. However, you can use `\lstinputlisting`.

The following approach uses a macro rather than an environment and requires using/writing to external files, but it might be useful.

1. Type the Python and Haskell source files (outside the `.tex` file, or inside, using `filecontents`).
2. Call the `\comparison` macro, which takes two arguments; the first being the relative path to the Python source file, and the second being that to the Haskell source file.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry} % the listings won't fit on the page otherwise
\usepackage{listings,xcolor}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\newcommand\comparison[2]%
{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
        \centering \textbf{Python}\\
        \lstinputlisting[frame=single,language=Python]{#1}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
        \centering \textbf{Haskell}\\
        \lstinputlisting[frame=single,language=Haskell]{#2}
    \end{minipage}
}

% Source file for Hello World in Python
\begin{filecontents*}{HelloWorldPython.py}
print "Hello, World!"
\end{filecontents*}

% Source file for Hello World in Haskell
\begin{filecontents*}{HelloWorldHaskell.hs}
module Main where
main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn "Hello, World!""
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\comparison{HelloWorldPython.py}{HelloWorldHaskell.hs}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I like this solution. I'll use that with additional `showstringspaces=false` (without underbar-like spaces in strings) to make it look more like original code and it's perfect.

Comment: It's still possible by collecting the content verbatim and `scantokens` it (or before that, write to file then `input`)