# enclosing a lstlisting environment inside my own environment using matlab-prettifier

Tags: listings, environments, matlab-prettifier

I've just started using `matlab-prettifier`.    Since the line `\begin{lstlisting}[style=Matlab-editor]` is a lot to type, I created my own environment:

```
\newenvironment{myMP}
     {\begin{samepage}\begin{lstlisting}[style=Matlab-editor]}
     {\end{lstlisting}\end{samepage}}
```

I've used this syntax many times before, but in this case it doesn't work.  Is there any reason why I can't enclose the `lstlisting` inside my own one?

Here's sample code, illustrating the problem.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[framed]{matlab-prettifier}%For matlab code
\newenvironment{myMP}
     {\begin{samepage} \begin{lstlisting}[style=Matlab-editor]}
     {\end{lstlisting} \end{samepage}}
\begin{document}
\begin{myMP}
matlab word
\end{myMP}
\end{document}
```

When I run this with `pdflatex` it returns a *, indicating that the environment wasn't closed properly.

Thanks!

Comment: Link to related question [macros - lstlisting in a newenvironment - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86705/lstlisting-in-a-newenvironment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't embed a verbatim - like environment like `lstlisting` inside another environment, at least not without much tricks (like `\scantokens` etc.)

`listings` provides the facility to generate own, customizable environments with `lstnewenvironment`. Use `\lstset{style=Matlab-editor}` to provide the relevant settings in the start-up-code section of the environment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[framed]{matlab-prettifier}%For matlab code



\lstnewenvironment{myMP}{%
  \lstset{style={Matlab-editor}%
  }
}{% End code -- empty here
}

\begin{document}
\begin{myMP}
  a = 1
  matlab word
\end{myMP}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works great, but I need to embed it in a conditional, i.e., I'm using the environment in an answer key.      So I want to do an \ifthen construction, of the form `\ifthenelse{\theanswerkey=1}{  \begin{myMP} a = 1 \end{myMP}} {}` where answerkey is a counter defined previously.      This construction runs into the usual problems associated with verbatim-like  environments.    Is there *some* way that I can do this?   Thanks!

Comment: @LeoSimon: That's another question and at the moment not answerable without seeing a real example