# Conditional formating of a verbatim type argument

Tags: conditionals, verbatim, matlab-prettifier

I write problem sets whose answer keys contain matlab code.    To accomplish this, I'm using `matlab-prettifier`, but I need to condition the output on whether I'm outputing the problem set questions or providing the answer key.    To accomplish this, I have been conditioning  on the setting of some counter; in the example below it's called `ctr`

But the following code throws an error, presumably because you can't put verbatim type environments inside of anything else, and the `listing` package consists of such environments.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcounter{ctr}
\setcounter{ctr}{1}
\usepackage{listing}
\usepackage[framed]{matlab-prettifier}
\lstnewenvironment{myMP}{%
    \lstset{style={Matlab-editor}}%
           }{}
\begin{document}
\ifthenelse{\thectr=1}{
    \begin{myMP}
        a = 1
    \end{myMP}
}{}
\end{document}
```

In [a previous posting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/304535/enclosing-a-lstlisting-environment-inside-my-own-environment-using-matlab-pretti) it was implied by [christian hupfer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/31729/christian-hupfer) that this *could* be accomplished with some tricks, included `scantokens` etc.

If it is at all possible to do this, could somebody please tell me where I can learn these tricks?   Thanks!   Or is there another indirect way of accomplishing conditional output?

Thanks!

Comment: `\ifnum\value{ctr}=1 <the code>\fi`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have verbatim-like environments in the arguments to `\ifthen`. But you can use the primitive conditionals.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listing}
\usepackage[framed]{matlab-prettifier}

\newcounter{ctr}
\setcounter{ctr}{1}

\lstnewenvironment{myMP}
 {\lstset{style={Matlab-editor}}}
 {}

\begin{document}

\ifnum\value{ctr}=1
\begin{myMP}
a = 1
\end{myMP}
\fi

\end{document}
```

Comment: This certainly works, thanks.     It would be some much nicer if we could enclose what you did in a macro, as in `\def\kludge#1{
    {}
    \ifnum\value{ctr}=1
        \begin{myMP}
            #1
    \end{myMP}
    \fi
}` but that doesn't seem to be possible

Comment: @LeoSimon No, it's not possible: once you have absorbed text as an argument, the meaning of the tokens is fixed *and* line breaks are lost.

Answer (score 1):

Here, I save the listing in a temporary `\vbox`, and only conditionally print it out.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcounter{ctr}
\setcounter{ctr}{1}
\usepackage{listing}
\usepackage[framed]{matlab-prettifier}
\lstnewenvironment{myMP}{%
    \lstset{style={Matlab-editor}}%
           }{}
\begin{document}
\setbox0=\vbox{%
    \begin{myMP}
        a = 1
    \end{myMP}
}
\ifthenelse{\thectr=1}{\box0}{Not!}
\end{document}
```