# Why doesn´t this new environment work?

Tags: environments, matlab, matlab-prettifier

I´m using the Matlab-prettifier package to include Matlab-code in my Latex-file, and it generally works, i.e, when I´m using the custom environment from the package:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[style=Matlab-editor]
format long
f=@(x) x^5 + x-1;
fzero(f, 1), hm(f, 0, 1, 0.5*10^-8)
ans =
   0.754877666246693

ans =
   0.754877667874098
\end{lstlisting}
```

So this works, but since this is an environment I use a lot, I would like to rename it to something shorter, and I´ve tried this:

```
\newenvironment{matlab}
{\begin{lstlisting}[style=Matlab-editor]}
{\end{lstlisting}}
```

That way I could just write

```
\begin{matlab}
Matlab-code here
\end{matlab}
```

to typeset the Matlab-code, but this doesn´t work, and I get a long and -- at least for me - incomprehensible error message, with a lot about undefined control sequences. Can anybody help me out with this? Thanks in advance!

Best answer (for me): [enclosing a lstlisting environment inside my own environment using matlab-prettifier](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/304535/enclosing-a-lstlisting-environment-inside-my-own-environment-using-matlab-pretti?rq=1)

Comment: do you really have blank lines in `\newenvironment{matlab}` definition?

Comment: Use `\VerbatimEnvironment`, for example, see here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171702/seemingly-trivial-verbatim-newenvironment-and-colorbox

Comment: @jfbu No, I don´t have a blank line in the definition, I just wanted each argument to be on a new line. Thanks for the edit!

Comment: If you're using listings, see section 5.14 of [the package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) for the `\lstnewenvironment` macro. You're running into a problem similar to the verbatim environment answer above, but the listings package has already solved it.

Comment: You can use the `{}` icon to convert a region into indented format making it rendered as code. I will suppress the blank lines.