# Danish character encoding broken with nested lstlisting

Tags: listings, input-encodings

In order to help TexStudio with its intellisense, I wrapped a `\lstnewenvironment` inside a `\newenvironment`. This allowed TeXStudio to properly highlight the newly defined environment.

However, when I do that and procede to write a danish character (æøå) then it will fail, saying the inputenc package cannot handle the character.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 

\lstnewenvironment{XJavaCode}[2]
    {\lstset{language=Java, caption=#1, label=#2}}
    {}

\newenvironment{JavaCode}[2]
    {\begin{XJavaCode}{#1}{#2}}
    {\end{XJavaCode}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{JavaCode}{caption}{label}
        ASD
    \end{JavaCode}
    æøå
\end{document}
```

Comment: It doesn't compile even if you remove the Danish characters.

Comment: See e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86705/103046) for an explanation. In short: `lstlisting` doesn't work properly within an user-defined environment, that's why `\lstnewenvironment` exists and why you should not wrap it inside another environment definition.

Comment: you can not include verbatim style environments in definitions in this way, that is precisely the reason why listings provides `\lstnewenvironment` as you can not use `\newenvironment`

Comment: Alright so there is no solution to this?
Seems a shame, as TeXStudio doesn't handle the `\lstnewenvironment` very well, but that's on them I guess.