# adjustwidth and newenvironment

Tags: listings, margins, adjustwidth, changepage

**Edit:** thank you for commenting. I've edited the question to use `lstnewenvironment` but it keeps giving the same error. I will keep the question here while I go read the `lstlistings` manual.

The following code works for me when used inside the document:

```
\begin{adjustwidth*}{0pt}{-5cm}
\begin{lstlisting}
function test() { return (void *) test_func(a, b, 3); }
\end{lstlisting}
\end{adjustwidth*}
```

But when I want to create a custom environment for it, Overleaf gives me the error

> job aborted, no legal \end found.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[right=10cm]{geometry}    % Create a large right margin
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{changepage}

% Create a new environment for code samples that can extend into the outer margin.
\lstnewenvironment{config}{%
   \begin{adjustwidth*}{0pt}{-5cm}
}{%
   \end{adjustwidth*}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{config}
function test() { return (void *) test_func(a, b, 3); } asdfasdfa asdf
\end{config}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The problematic part here is not the `adjustwidth` environment but `lstlisting`. `\newenvironment{config}{\begin{lstlisting}}{\end{lstlisting}}` causes the same error message that you observewith your original definition of the `config` environment.

Comment: In order to create a new environment containing a `lstlisting`, the `listings` package offers `\lstnewenvironment`. See also: [lstlisting in a newenvironment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86705/134144)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, `changepage` and `listings` fight each other. However, you don't need `changepage` for this application.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[right=10cm]{geometry}    % Create a large right margin
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Create a new environment for code samples that can extend into the outer margin.
\lstnewenvironment{config}[1][]{\lstset{xrightmargin=-5cm,#1}}{}

\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,columns=fullflexible} % so my eyes don't bleed

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4]

\begin{config}
function test() { return (void *) test_func(a, b, 3); } asdfasdfa asdf
\end{config}

\end{document}
```

You can add `listings` options to `config` in the usual way, by calling `\begin{config}[]

[image]